# mod rewrite: how to check if url exists else redirect path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am quite new to mod rewrite and i have this, which is not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kitnes/cache/dynamic/$1.htm

RewriteRule /kitnes/cache/dynamic/([^/\.]+).htm index.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

the rewritten URL is something like this http://www.ghananewsportal.com/1.1629334 and i would like it to redirect to http://www.ghananewsportal.com/?id=1.1629334 if the rewritten URL fails.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/kitnes/cache/dynamic/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /kitnes/cache/dynamic/$1.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```